# Python numpy - IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: numpy, indexing

I'm fairly new to python but this example just won't work for me. I believe it's meant to index x but I'm not 100% sure.

```
import numpy as np

y = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,2,4,1,9])
x = np.array(['e','l','t','d','m','f','c','j','x','a'])

print
print
print "Y"
print type(y)
print y
print
print
print "X"
print type(x)
print x
print
print


result = x[0, y]
```

The exact error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "test.py", line 20, in <module>
result = x[0, y]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

Comment: What is your expected outcome? What should `result` look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand what I was doing wrong now, x was supposed to be  `np.array([['e','l','t','d','m','f','c','j','x','a']])`,
not `x = np.array(['e','l','t','d','m','f','c','j','x','a'])`

Thanks for the responses!

Answer (score 0):

To get a value from an array, you must use `x[index]`. You can not get a value passing 2 arguments in the brackets

Answer (score 0):

`x` is not a multidimensional array. You have to append 0 to y:

```
 result = x[0+y]
```